# Getting check box values as checked from database codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, checked

I'm trying to get check box values inserted into my database as checked.. I'd inserted it using the implode method as string. It inserted the values successfully., but my condition to get the check box value "checked" is not working..

```
<label>Some text</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text1" 
<?php echo set_checkbox('text', $row->Some_text)== 'text1' ? "checked" : "";?>>text1
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text2" 
<?php echo set_checkbox('text', $row->Some_text)== 'text2' ? "checked" : "";?>>text2
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text3" 
<?php echo set_checkbox('text', $row->Some_text)== 'text3' ? "checked" : "";?>>text3 
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text4" 
<?php echo set_checkbox('text', $row->Some_text)== 'text4' ? "checked" : "";?>>text4
```

I wrote model for edit as :

```
public function edit($id)
    {
    $sometext = $this->input->post('text');
        $data=array(
        'Some_text'=>json_encode(implode(",", $sometext)),
        );
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('User_id',$id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_check');
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_check');
        return $query->row();
        }
```

And edit is working well..

Comment: It's a tad confusing but, have you tried wrapping the set_checkbox and == 'text' in ()? Like so `echo (set_checkbox('text', $row->Some_text)== 'text1') ? "checked" : "";?>`

Comment: I guess you should wrap everything: `echo ((set_checkbox('text', $row->Some_text)== 'text1') ? "checked" : "");?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the use of functions from frameworks just make it totally unnecessarily and *dirtier*.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text1" <?php echo ($yourVar == 'text1' ? 'checked' : null); ?>>
```

Comment: What is this method called that can do this without if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Just get the data from the Model. and pass it to the check box page.

```
$data['check_box_data']=$query->row_array();
$this->load->view('page',$data);
```

View:

```
<?php 
    $c_box1=$c_box2=$c_box3='';
    $chk_data=explode(',',$chk_box_data); // $chk_box_data is which is from DB
    foreach($chk_data as $list)
    {
      //chk_box1_value1,2,3 are original check box values
      if($list=='chk_box1_value'){$c_box1='checked';}
      if($list=='chk_box2_value'){$c_box2='checked';}
      if($list=='chk_box3_value'){$c_box3='checked';}
    }
?>

label>Some text</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text1" 
<?php echo $c_box1;?>>text1
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text2" 
<?php echo $c_box2;?>>text2
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text3" 
<?php echo $c_box3;?>>text3
```

Try this....

Answer (score 1):

Using standard CodeIgniter functions:

```
form_checkbox('fieldname', '1', set_checkbox('fieldname', '1', (TEST YOUR DB DATA HERE)));
```

**Example**:

```
form_checkbox('fieldname', '1', set_checkbox('fieldname', '1', (!empty($data_from_db))));
```

**Explanation**:
`set_checkbox()` determines whether to output `checked="checked"` and thus show your field as checkmarked or not.

The *third parameter* of set_checkbox() determines whether the **initial state of your checkbox will checked/not-checked**.  If the third parameter evaluates to `TRUE` the first time the form is loaded, the checkbox will be ticked; if it evaluates to `FALSE`, it won't be marked.

So, when editing data from a table, use the Controller to get the data from the table and pass it to the form.  In your form, test the data from your table in the third parameter of set_checkbox().

In my example above, the data for FIELDNAME was stored in the table as "1" or "0".

When the edit form is loaded, the third parameter of SET_CHECKBOX tests, "Is the data from the table empty?"  If there is data, `!empty()` returns TRUE, causing set_checkbox() to set the DEFAULT STATE to CHECKED.

The key is using the THIRD PARAMETER of set_checkbox() to evaluate your existing value.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `set_checkbox` incorrectly. Look at the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html): do not use this in a conditional statement. Your question doesn't give much information, but I assume you want something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text1" 
<?php echo set_checkbox('text[]', 'text1');?>>text1
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text2" 
<?php echo set_checkbox('text', 'text2');?>>text2
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text3" 
<?php echo set_checkbox('text', 'text3');?>>text3 
<input type="checkbox" name="text[]" value="text4" 
<?php echo set_checkbox('text', 'text4');?>>text4
```